# Magento homepage on a custom theme NOT showing after catalog URL rewrites?

Tags: php, magento, mod-rewrite, ssh, url-rewriting

I recently uploaded products to a new Magento site through CSV data profiles import.

The catalog url rewrites was stuck on 'Processing' after that and I couldn't rewrite them through the Magento admin backend, so I used SSH to rewrite the URLs through a query on indexer.php

As soon as I did that, the homepage is not showing up properly anymore. Only the header and footer is showing up. The blocks in the middle are missing.

To rectify, I TRUNCATED the catalog URLs table and the homepage was back on with no problems at all but then the rewrites are gone and the links don't work well. So I reindexed them through SSH again.

Now the homepage problem persists, it's not showing up.

Any ideas on this would be appreciated!

Comment: check the format data that stored at catalog URL. Might be your custom theme has a different format for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure one of your products doesn't have a blank `URL Key` or just a space (this is a possibility when importing products).

What will happen if this is the case is that Magento will create a URL Index for `/` which will cause issues with the homepage loading.

You can double-check if this is the case by looking in the `core_url_rewrite` database table and looking for a blank or `/` value inside of the `request_path` column.